# external access to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

```
docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v${K8S_VERSION} \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
        --containerized \
        --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
        --address="0.0.0.0" \
        --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
        --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
        --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
        --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
        --allow-privileged=true --v=2
```

A `curl localhost:8080`confirms that the API is running.

But trying to access it with the host's IP like `curl dockerHostIp:8080`fails:

```
Failed to connect to ipOfDockerHost port 8080: Connection refused
```

How can I expose k8s to the outside? (docker-host is an ubuntu server)
As far as I understand using --net=host should solve this problem. But it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start kubernetes with docker, you choose between two models:

- [--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master.json)
- [--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master-multi.json).

If you look in these files, you will notice one difference: `--insecure-bind-address is different`.

When you use `--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests`, you ask for a local access only.

You should start with `--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi`.

Note that:

- you will need to start etcd manually when you use --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi
- follow [this post](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869) as docker support is not working for now

Comment: one more thing: executing `kubectl get ep` may be helpful as well.

Comment: @geoHeil. `kubectl get ep` return the secured port. How do you get the credentials ? For now I locate them in `/data` in the `setup-files.sh` container started by hyperkube. But I don't really know how to translate them ...

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/admin/authentication.md) is certainly the good documentation start point